# Print Data from Confluent Source and Sink connectors

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

i have source and sink connectors installed using confluent and they are working fine. but when i see docker logs using

```
docker logs -f container-name
```

the output is something like this

```
[2018-09-19 09:44:06,571] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=mariadb-source-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask)
[2018-09-19 09:44:06,571] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=mariadb-source-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask)
[2018-09-19 09:44:06,573] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=mariadb-source-0} Finished commitOffsets successfully in 2 ms (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask)
[2018-09-19 09:44:16,194] INFO WorkerSinkTask{id=oracle-sink-0} Committing offsets asynchronously using sequence number 1077: {faheemuserdbtest-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=7, metadata=''}} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
[2018-09-19 09:44:16,574] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=mariadb-source-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask)
[2018-09-19 09:44:16,574] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=mariadb-source-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTas
```

but it doesn't the actual data going through the topics, is there a way i can print that data in logs? because i'm moving these logs to a kibana dashboard.
yes i can read data from Kafka topic but that is not my scenario.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to see the actual records from Kafka Connect logs. Usually, the records that appear in the logs are those which have failed to be replicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the connector, if you enabled TRACE logging in the Connector Log4j properties, you can see the messages.

If using the Confluent's docker images, there are some `CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS` environment variables for controlling that

If you want the actual JDBC data in Elasticsearch, you'd typically install the Elasticsearch sink, though rather than parse it out of those logs

Comment: yes i am using the confluent docker images

here is the CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS environment variable in connect section of docker-compose.yml

CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR

can you specifiy how am i supposed to change it?

Comment: You need to know the classname of the process you want to change, then just follow the format that you already have

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't see that data in the logs.

The connectors don't print the actual data copied around. If you have such requirement, you probably would have to change the logging mechanism in the source and sink connector source code  and customize it according to your requirement.